# PHP file_get_contents() not working on FreeBSD 9.3

Tags: php, freebsd

I'm trying to open a remote data source in PHP 5.6 using file_get_contents() on a FreeBSD 9.3 server.  The function in failing returning a NULL.  Naturally, I first checked /usr/local/etc/php.ini and, sure enough, I have allow_url_fopen = On.  Just for good measure I also turned allow_url_include = On as well.

php --ini says that the php.ini file is correctly placed in /usr/local/etc.  php_info() says allow_url_fopen is On.  However, I can't get file_get_contents() to work.  I can pull the same URL with curl on the command line with no problem, and the URL contains no special characters or variables, and I've enclosed it in single quotes.  PHP otherwise seems to work fine on the server.

I'm using the latest pre-built PHP 5.6 package that can be downloaded from FreeBSD depositories.

What's going on here?  I can't figure what's going on.

Comment: Are you `urlencode`-ing the URI? I've gotten caught up with that before.

Comment: No, but the same code is working on another server (very different configuration, and I don't have access to it).